# Why can't an implementing method have an argument

Tags: java

For this:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SwingExample11 extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    public SwingExample11() {
        initUI();
    }   
    private void initUI() {
        setTitle("SwingExample1");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   
    @Override
    public void run(SwingExample11 ex) {
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        SwingExample11 ex = new SwingExample11();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(ex);
    }   
}
```

I get:

```
6: error: SwingExample11 is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in Runnable
public class SwingExample11 extends JFrame implements Runnable {
^
16: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
```

When I remove the argument and the code block from `run()` it compiles, but obviously doesn’t do anything.

When I implement an interface I thought I could write the method however I wanted? Is it because its an abstract method? I thought all interface methods were abstract by default, and anyway, I thought if you `@Override` a method then you can do what you want with it.

I think I am confused with abstract methods. Where am I going wrong please, and what will make me understand things more clearly?

Comment: "I thought I could write the method however I wanted" - that assumption is incorrect.  I'm not sure what else to say...

Comment: Because if you add an argument to the method you change its signature and you are no-longer overriding the method, you are adding a different method.

Comment: Apart from the fundamental misunderstandings of how abstract methods work, this seems to be a XY problem, so why don't you step back and tell what you want to do exactly?

Comment: You can't change the method signature...  However you can have setter to set a property and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the way inheritance works. If you implement the `run` method from the interface `Runnable`, anyone calling this run method on the interface itself should execute the run method you had implemented.

So if there's code somewhere `Runnable r = new SwingExample11()` and then `r.run()` this is meant to execute the `run` method in your `SwingExample11` class, without any parameter, but your overridden method actually expects a parameter - what should be it's value?

Because of this the signature has to be exactly the same, otherwise the whole inheritance concept in the type system would break down (specifically the [substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: You created a reference variable of type `Runnable` (which is an interface). Then a `SwingExample11` object. Then assigned the object to the reference. I didn't know you could assign objects to a reference that is not their class. e.g `SwingExample11 ex = new SwingExample11()`. What is `r` ?!

Comment: That's one of the basic concept of object oriented programming. I would recommend to read a book or a tutorial on that.

Comment: `Runnable r = new SwingExample11()`. `new SwingExample11()` tells Java to make a new object using the `SwingExample11()` blueprint. Java creates a reference to this new object, called `r`, which you can use to access this new object. What does having the word `Runnable` do in that line??? It means that `r` is of type `Runnable`. e.g. it is a remote-control that has buttons to control something that implements a `Runnable` interface right??

Comment: I believe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) answers my last comment - "If you define a reference variable whose type is an interface, any object you assign to it must be an instance of a class that implements the interface."

Answer (score 2):

In java method signature consists of method name and its argument types. This is the basics of method overloading (same method name, but different argument types).

run(void) is not the same as run(SwingExample11).

This is because at runtime JVM will look for a method with name run and takes no arguments. Since you have only defined a method with name "run" and takes one argument of type "SwingExample11", there are no method with name "run" taking no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the method signature while implementing.You can provide your own implementation of that method provided method signature remains intact.

Comment: OK, but you CAN add/change method body in this case, right?

Answer (score 1):

A method's signature consists of 3 parts, return type, method name, parameters and throws clause.

When you are implementing a method from an interface, you must override every method. This means that the methods signatures must match up. Here when you added  an extra parameter,

```
@Override
public void run(SwingExample11 ex) {
    ex.setVisible(true);
}
```

your method is no longer the method that you need to implement, and is a completely new method.

EDIT: Thanks to the comments for correcting me

Comment: Also important to mention that "match up" is slightly more complicated than just being exactly the same. And another thing: thrown exceptions must match up too.

Comment: Technically,  4 parts - the `throws` clause is the 4th